# EF Multiple databases with different versions

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am working on an API that works with different instances of a database from a Webshop framework. When a call is received the API gets the database string that belongs to that specific webshop so that it is able to work with it's data.

This all works pretty well with Entity Framework (database first). But now we want to upgrade one of the webshops to a newer version of the framework. In that version there are a few small changes to it's database. Because some of the new columns are not nullable i had to change the models in the API so that i was able to insert values.

We really want to keep the support for the previous version of the framework. But now when we try to insert with the new DataContext it says that some column names are invalid as they are not in the previous version.

The Question is if it's possible to somehow let Entity Framework ignore invalid column names Or if it's possible to tell Entity Framework in which version the database exists to let it use a different model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions:

1 You need two databases: the first will be the new version, the second will be the old version and you keep them sync if needed.

2 You use a single database and only the new version has direct access to it. In this case you will need to implement an API at the new version and requests from old version would be converted using this API into new-version requests.

3 You can upgrade the old versions to new version.

Comment: You're right. After a quick talk with the others we decided to stick everything to the new version and just keep the code base for the old one apart. Might we ever need it. Thanks for your quick answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible at the moment.

What I would do is create an individual DbContext for each database (version) and 1 POCO model per version as well